# add/remove products to favorites in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm creating a project on mobile comparison and i'm using web-scraping for getting the mobile's data and directly rendering it on web-browser without creating any product's model for saving the data.

note: i have created User's model

[image: like this]

i want to create add/remove favorite functionality. when user click on the heart icon, it should be added as favourite.

but i do not know how to do this without having model.

please help me to solve it.

thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the problem if you create the model?

Comment: i dont need any model for storing the product's data. cause i'm directly rendering the product's data on browser.

Comment: Suppose I liked one product if next time I visit the same site then it should show me my liked product right?. So to store the data i.e. a particular user has liked this product what you will do.

Comment: yess!!! should i create a favorite model and set a ManytoMany relationship with the User model?

Comment: You should have 2 Models one for storing the product details and one favourite model with user and produc as foreign key in it. So basically in your favourite model you create 3 columns:a)product,b)user,c)status:True/False. As the user like product insert the data in favourite model with status as True and next time if he dislike the product just change the status from True to False

Answer (score 1):

Let say you have 3 tables like thsi:

```
**Product:**               

 id   name      price    
  1  'iphone'    36000     
  2  'redmi-6'   8000          

**User:** 

 id  username
 1  'chirag' 
 2   'priyank' 

**Favourite:**

id product_id user_id  status
1   1           2        True
2   2           1        False
```

You just need to crate 2 tables product and favourite. The user table you can use that one provided by django. Import it like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: but why should i create a product's model. is there any way when user click on the add like icon the product's name goes to the user_fav model

Comment: First you tell me that you are always have same products or the products will change day by day?

Comment: what do you mean by change day by day. its showing the products on the basis of price filter

Comment: I mean the data you are getting from web scraping will not always be same right?

Comment: i.e. suppose today you got few mobiles in result but next day you can get few more and so on.

Comment: Not boasting by answering but to get good and good result make a habit of appreciating the people who answer your question even if you got a little idea from them.

Comment: yess..result will change little bit..after new mobile launched

Comment: So you make one Product table to store the product data i.e. mobile id, name, brand etc. Then if somebody likes that product for which data got stored in the product table, get that product id and store that in favourite table along with user id and status as I suggested.

Comment: I hope I no need to explain all the things that from where you will get the user id. To get the user id simple do `request.user`

Comment: i think you don't understand my qustion.. i'm saying i'm not storing any scrape data. i directly rendering it on browser as a json

Comment: I know that you are getting the JSON and rendering it directly. But why I am telling you to store the product id is because if the user has liked any product earlier then for that product you can show the red color like icon to the user by comparing the product id that you stored with the one that you are getting in json response.

Comment: To get the practical idea I will suggest you that go over the flipkart website and like any product, then logout and then second time visit the same site you will see your liked product over there.